# A fun-loving meme

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> A fun-loving meme,
>
> A snack filled with cream.
>
> One whom most can't visit,
>
> Body beyond limit.
>
> A signature of the king,
>
> A view of nothing between.
>
> A light melody to tide you over,
>
> Feelings and you lose your composure.

Who am i?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fun loving meme

> "Moon Moon" (the wolf meme)

A snack filled with cream

> A Moon Pie

One whom most can't visit

> Very few visit our own Moon

Body Beyond Limit

> Refers to the Roche Limit. If a moon is inside the Roche Limit of the planet it is orbiting, it will break up due to the planet's gravity affecting the moon greater than the moon's own gravity holding it together. Therefore, moons must be "beyond" the Roche Limit.

A signature of the King

> Moonwalk, famously known as a dance move by Michael Jackson, dubbed "the King of Pop"

A view of nothing between

> Is about the act of "Mooning" at someone (Pointing your bare buttocks towards them)

A light melody to tide you over

> Moonlight Sonata by Beethoven. "Light">"Moonlight", "Melody">"Sonata", used as a lullaby (To "tide people over" into sleep)

Feelings and you lose your composure

> "Mooning" over someone, to have feelings for them and not think straight when it comes to matters about them.

The Answer:

> All the above are linked by the Moon. Since the question specifically asks "Who", not "What", then the answer is "The Man in the Moon!"

Answer (score 0):

partial answer:
A fun-loving meme,

> a Rick Roll

A snack filled with cream.

> A cream roll? Some kind of Pastry roll?